# CSS class doesn't work

Tags: html, css

In http://tpgf7.nicolapps.ch/000555/, when you click the top left button, there is a « Twitter » button in the panel, but it doesn't have the right `background-color`. This is my CSS :

```
.social .twitter {
    background-color:#55acee;
    border: 1px solid #55acee;
}
```

But this doesn't work. However, the Facebook button works.

Comment: Please include your code inside your question for future visitors.

Comment: Are you sure you added the css to the site? Inspecting the site I cannot see any css rule for the social or twitter class

Comment: There is no sighn of this style in DevTools, check its nesting, may there is wrong parent?

Comment: Final solution is posted in my answer, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside **/resources/css/tpgwidget.css** I've found this:

```
.social .twitterÂ {
    background-color:#55acee;
    border: 1px solid #55acee;
}
```

This is how your .css file looks like, so the **special char at the end** may be causing your problems. If you remove this char after class name, everything should be displayer properly, nothing else.

Comment: This is right answer! I deleted space between twitter. and { and style applyed.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, mark the answer as the right one if the problem is gone.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśniak Thank you very much ! It was displayed like this in my text editor :

http://cdn.nicolapps.ch/images/uploads/1440325493.png

Comment: Of course you're welcome, sir!

Answer (score 0):

There is no twitter class in your stylesheet.Now twitter button accept background color from ".button.active" class.

You should add class ".social .twitter{}" in your stylesheet then you can style twitter button as your needed.Hope this will be work.

Answer (score 0):

.button.active {background: #55acee;color: #fff;}